# expected 1 norm of a normal vector

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Given a normal vector $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$ and $Cov(X)=Id$, is it possible to get an expression for
$$\mathbb{E}(\|A X\|_1)$$
where $A$ is a given matrix.
I know that in dimension 1, we have
$$\mathbb{E}(|a X|) = |a|\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$
but can we generalize this result?
Thanks.

Charles

Comment: How is $A$ defined?

Comment: $A$ could be any matrix (I ve updated the message). What I want is something similar to $\mathbb{E}(\| AX \|_2^2) = tr(A^t A) = \| A \|_F^2$ but in the case of the l1 norm. However, if I have an expression only in the case where $A$ is a projector and/or symmetric, I would be satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is actualy trivial
$$
\mathbb{E}(\left\| AX \right\|_1) = \left\| A \right\|_{1,2} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}
$$

proof: We have by linearity of the expectation $\mathbb{E}(\left\| AX \right\|_1) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{E}(| (AX)_i |)$. Moreover, $(AX)_i = \sum_{j = 1}^m a_{ij} X_j$. Since the $X_j$ are iid with distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, we have $(AX)_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sum a_{ij}^2)$ and then $\mathbb{E}|(AX)_i|=\sqrt{\sum_{j = 1}^m  a_{ij}^2} \sqrt{2/\pi}$. We conclude by using the definition of the $\ell_{1,2}$ norm: $\sum_{i = 1}^n \sqrt{\sum_{j = 1}^m  a_{ij}^2} = \left\| A\right\|_{1,2}$.